# Power BI: Latitude/Longitude points to total different places

Tags: google-maps

I am starting with PBI Desktop and want to place my customers on a map.
I have a view from SQL Server with Postcode, City, Latitude, Longitude, for example:

1010, Wien, 48.2073308, 16.373384

when I put lat/Long in Google maps it is perfectly in the heart of Vienna/Austria, correct.

In PBI it is somewhere near Memphis/USA. 
On top of that, if I turn the coordination the other way round, Long/lat =48.2073308, 16.373384 I find a spot in the Dessert of Yemenia and not Memphis.
Any idea, whats wrong there??
Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it to work.
Lan/lon is not enough, you must add a City or post code.
I do not know why, because GPS coordinates are unique but without a City they can not be assigned correct obviously.

Michael